# Maximize sum of squares of subset sum of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Suppose I've been given an array A of size N and I want to find to find the maximum possible sum of squares of subsets of the array. How do I do this? Do we need DP for this?

Comment: No, because it is square so every number is positive just use the whole set and it is maximum.

Comment: And if you want the square of sum subset to be maximized then put all positive numbers in one set and all negative numbers in other and calculate the value and then check which one is bigger!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a math question actually.

To obtain a larger number, it is always better to sum numbers of the same sign before squaring them.

So the maximum is obtained for the sum square of positive elements + the sum square of negative elements.

Comment: Provable via the summation mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number#Properties)